# MongoStat via cron to file?

Tags: linux, cron, mongodb

I'm looking to run mongostat command and have that export out to a file... Wondering if its OK to run this via cron giving that its a continuious stream of data does that work OK if I enter the command as a cron? Is there a better way?

I want to ensure that if the server gets rebooted that the command starts running automatically hence I don't want to just run it as my user.

Thoughts?

Comment: looks like nohup might be of some use...

Comment: What is your intended `mongostat` polling interval? The default output of every second wouldn't be suitable for a `cron` job which typically has a one minute granularity. In this case, `nohup` or similar would be more appropriate to start and continue collecting `mongostat` output in the background. Also, what is your goal in terms of collecting this data? If you're after a continuous stream of MongoDB metrics, an agent based approach would be better, ideally with charts & alerting. For example, you could use MongoDB Cloud or Ops Manager.